# Should there be only one EventSource object per app?

Tags: javascript, html, http, push, server-sent-events

When using [Server-Sent Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) should the client establish multiple connections to receive different events it is interested in, or should there be a single connection and the client indicates what it is interested via a separate channel? IMO the latter seems more preferable although to some it might make the client code more complex. The spec supports named events (events that relate to a particular topic), which to me suggests that a Server-Sent Events connection should be used as single channel for all events.

The following code illustrates the first scenario where a multiple Server-Sent Event connections are initiated:

```
var EventSource eventSource1 = new EventSource("events/topic1");
eventSource1.addEventListener('topic1', topic1Listener, false);

var EventSource eventSource2 = new EventSource("events/topic2");
eventSource2.addEventListener('topic2', topic2Listener, false);
```

eventSource1 would receive "topic1" events and eventSource2 would receive "topic2" events. Whilst this is pretty straight forward it is also pretty inefficient with a hanging GET occurring for each topic you are interested in.

The alternative is something like the following:

```
var EventSource eventSource3 = new EventSource("/events?id=1234")
eventSource3.addEventListener('topic3', topic3Listener, false);
eventSource3.addEventListener('topic4', topic4Listener, false);

var subscription = new XMLHttpRequest();
subscription.open("PUT", "/events/topic3?id=1234", true);
subscription.send();
```

In this example a single EventSource would exist and interest in a particular event would be specified by a separate request with the Server-Sent Event connection and the registration being correlated by the id param. topic3Listener would receive "topic3" events and topic4Listener would not. Whilst requiring slightly more code the benefit is that only a single connection is made, but events can be still be identified and handled differently.

There are a number examples on the web that show the use of named events, but it seems the event names (or topics) are known in advance so there is no need for a client to register interest with the server ([example](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/06/a-wall-powered-by-eventsource-and-server-sent-events/)). Whilst I am yet to see an example showing multiple EventSource objects, I also haven't seen an example showing a client using a separate request to register interest in a particular topic, as I am doing above. My interpretation of the spec leads me to believe that indicating an interest in a certain topic (or event name) is entirely up to the developer and that it can be done statically with the client knowing the names of the events it is going to receive or dynamically with the client alerting the server that it is interested in receiving particular events.

I would be pretty interested in hearing other people's thoughts on the topic. NB: I am usually a Java dev so please forgive my mediocre JS code.. :)

Comment: you may not use at all event names in your event-stream, instead you can listen for "message" event and in the event.data you can encode your topicId and additional info

Comment: Yeah sure, but that would mean that I need to encode such data in payload which doesn't really make sense when message identification is already part of the spec's data framing.

Comment: +1 ! very good question. What did you end up doing ? I am also thinking of going with the second approach. Would appreciate if you share whether you ran into any problems with it.

Comment: @JamesTyrrell which solution did you choose? Could you please share your experience in few words (or even better in article on medium.com :))?

Answer (score 7):

I would highly recommend, IMHO, that you have one `EventSource` object per SSE-providing service, and then emit the messages using different types.

Ultimately, though, it depends on how similar the message types are.  For example, if you have 5 different types of messages related to users, have a user `EventSource` and differentiate with event types.

If you have one event type about users, and another about sandwiches, I'd say keep them in different services, and thus `EventSource`s.

It's a good idea to think of breaking up EventSources the same way you would a restful service.  If you wouldn't get two things from the same service with AJAX, you probably shouldn't get them from the same EventSource.

Comment: Does that scale?

Comment: From an architecture/structure perspective I agree (for all the reasons you mentioned), but there is a cost associated with the connection limits: You either support HTTP/2 (incl. mandatory end-to-end TLS) or a workaround like having a subdomain per SSE service. Both can be cumbersome for various reasons, so it's a trade-off.

Comment: @saml , how would that work if one passes parameters in the `EventSource` url?

Answer (score 1):

In response to vague and permissive browser standard interpretation*, browser vendors have inconsistently implemented restrictions to the number of persistent connections allowed to a single domain/port. As each event receiver to an async context assumes a single persistent connection allocation for as long as that receiver is open, it is crucial that the number of the EventSource listeners be strictly limited in order to avoid exceeding the varying, vendor-specific limits.  In practice this limits you to about 6 EventSource/async context pairs per application.  Degradation is graceful (e.g. additional EventSource connection requests will merely wait until a slot is available), but keep in mind there must be connections available for retrieving page resources, responding to XHR, etc.

*The W3C has issued standards with respect to persistent connections that contain language “… SHOULD limit the number of simultaneous connections…” This language means the standard is not mandatory so vendor compliance is variable.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4